# Aim the lasers up

Tags: wordplay, letters, quote

Start with the phrase “Aim the lasers up” and perform the following steps in some order to reveal **a popular lyric**:

- Break a word in two
- Change a letter
- Combine two words
- Rearrange the letters of a word
- Rearrange the letters of a word
- Remove two letters from a word

Comment: There seem to have been an awful lot of these lately.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I think I have a problem. And I infected a couple of others. :)

Comment: A shame, really

Comment: @Den It is a shame when a question bombs. It would be a bigger shame if there were no questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the lyric

> I am the walrus?

**Steps:**
Rearrange:

> Iam the lasers up

Break:

> I am the lasers up

Change a letter:

> I am the laserw up

Combine:

> I am the laserwup

Rearrange:

> I am the walruspe

Remove two letters:

> I am the walrus

Comment: I was trying to work this out for so long and I assumed the steps had to be in order so I couldn't find anything that worked

Comment: Yeah, it did say in some order but easy to miss if you skim over that part :P I am not satisfied however - the intermediate words don't make sense!